# Randomizing Array Values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, splice

I have a 4x4 array.

Initially the values are all set to 0, however I want to change innermost 2x2 values to a random float.

```
 a = np.zeros((4,4))
 print(a)
 a[1:3,1:3] = random.uniform(-1,1)
 print(a)
```

Creates an output:

```
 [[0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.66529858 0.66529858 0.        ]
  [0.         0.66529858 0.66529858 0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

When the desired outcome would be:

```
 [[0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.random0  0.random1 0.        ]
  [0.         0.random2  0.random3 0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `size` argument to generate a 2 by 2 random matrix:

```
a[1:3,1:3] = random.uniform(-1,1,size=(2,2))
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with an explanation. That would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service. It probably also improves your chance at being perceived as helpful and upvoted.